# ajax.responseText is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a website and I want to plot some points on a map.

My points are in a database and I call it from PHP to get the dataset.
That part works fine :

```
connexion.php

<?php
function connectBdd(){

$host_bdd='localhost';
$name_bdd='TBMigrateurs';
$user_bdd='postgres';
$pass_bdd='eptbmig';

try{
  $bdd = new PDO ("pgsql:host=".$host_bdd.";dbname=".$name_bdd."", "".$user_bdd."", "".$pass_bdd."") or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
  $bdd->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
  $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
}

catch(Exeption $e){
  die("Erreur!".$e->getMessage());
}

// On récupère les données
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM ouvrages');

//On affiche chaque entrée une à une
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
$latitude[] = $donnees['xl93'];
$longitude[] = $donnees['yl93'];
}

$reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête

echo (string)$latitude[5];
//echo $longitude[0];
}
?>
```

The latitude of my 5th point is plot correctly on the page.
Now I want to catch it in Javascript thanks to Ajax :

```
map.js

// création de l'objet xhr
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
// destination et type de la requête AJAX (asynchrone ou non)
ajax.open('POST', 'connexion.php', true);

ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

ajax.addEventListener('load',  function(e) {
    // si l'état est le numéro 4 et que la ressource est trouvée
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        // le texte de la réponse
        var lat = ajax.responseText;
        console.log(lat);
    }
});

// envoi de la requête
ajax.send();
```

And here "lat" is empty and the value in PHP is still plot on my website.
For me it seems that AJAX does not know what it should take from the PHP file so it takes nothing.

Does someone know why my ajax.responseText is empty ?
Thank you

**EDIT**

I mentionned only the parts of my code which have problems. "connexion.php" is called from the "index.php" file, which is the one plotting the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- appel du style de la librairie leaflet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <!-- appel du style créé sur le poste-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="accueil.css" />
    <!-- appel de la librairie leaflet-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <!-- appel du js créé sur le poste-->
    <script src="map.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="leaflet-providers.js"></script>-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>

      <h1> Tableau de bord de la continuité écologique </h1>

    </header>


    <div id="mapid">
      <!-- la carte-->
    </div>

    <p>Ici</p>
    <div id="pays">Pays </div>
    <p> La </p>

    <?php
   include 'connexion.php';
   connectBdd();
   ?>



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was mixing everything .. I want to get PHP variables into my javascript file.

I tried to do that with ajax while ajax send Javascript variables to PHP (I want to do the contrary).

So it could not work. I post the solution if someone need it. I created a javascript function that I call from PHP, with my PHP variables as parameters.

For each coordinate, I call the js function that plot a point on the map.

connexion.php

```
// On récupère les données
   $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM ouvrages');

//On affiche chaque entrée une à une
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
  //coordonnees de l'ouvrage
  $latitude = $donnees['xl93'];
  $longitude = $donnees['yl93'];

  $impact = $donnees['impact'];

  ?>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="l93_to_wgs84.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  affichage_ouvrage(lambert93toWGPS('<?PHP echo $latitude;?>','<?PHP echo $longitude;?>')['latitude'],lambert93toWGPS('<?PHP echo $latitude;?>','<?PHP echo $longitude;?>')['longitude'],'<?PHP echo $impact;?>');
  </script>

  <?php
}
$reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête


}

?>
```

map.js

```
function affichage_ouvrage(latitude,longitude,impact){

  if (impact == 'Faible'){
  var ouvrage = L.marker([latitude,longitude],{icon: blueSmallIcon}).addTo(map);
  }
  else if (impact == 'Moyen'){
  var ouvrage = L.marker([latitude,longitude],{icon: greenSmallIcon}).addTo(map);
  }
  else if (impact == 'Fort'){
  var ouvrage = L.marker([latitude,longitude],{icon: orangeSmallIcon}).addTo(map);
  }
  else if (impact == 'Tres_fort'){
  var ouvrage = L.marker([latitude,longitude],{icon: redSmallIcon}).addTo(map);
  }
  else {
  var ouvrage = L.marker([latitude,longitude],{icon: unvisiSmallIcon}).addTo(map);
  }

ouvrage.bindPopup("Hi there !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code never **calls** `connectBdd`, it just defines it. You need to call it, e.g.:

```
connectBdd();
```

at the end of the file.

Also note that your XHR call is calling `connexion.php` but your comment at the top of the code block says it's called `connection.php`.

Comment: Unless *"...and the value in PHP is still plot on my website."* means you're seeing somethign to suggest that the code in the PHP file actually ran, in which case you must have left part of the file out in the question (or perhaps it's observational error?).

Comment: Indeed the function is called by my main file, sorry. I edited my post to include the "index.php" file. Moreover, it's "connexion.php" you are right. So the problem does not come from here/